# alpha number 0-255 equivalent in 0-127 range

Tags: php, math, image-processing, gd

I have a rgba color in which alpha value is in 0-255 range. now i am using this function imagecolorallocatealpha in php it accept alpha value in 0-127 range.how can i convert my alpha value that is in 0-255 to 0-127

```
for example 
Alpha = 255
equivalent in 0-127 = 127

Alpha = 0
equivelent in 0-127 = 0
```

Comment: Neglecting the least significant bit and hence dividing by two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $Red, $Green, $Blue, $Alpha/2);
```

instead of

```
imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $Red, $Green, $Blue, $Alpha);

Example 
Alpha = 255
equivalent in 0-127 = 127  as (255/2 = 127.5)

Alpha = 0
equivelent in 0-127 = 0   as (0/2 = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comment suggest, dividing by 2 seems like a good idea.

```
$Alpha_in_127_scale = round($Alpha / 2, 0);
```

I know round() rounds to zero decimal places by default, but it's different in different languages, so I like to specify it for easier reading.